# Event not available anymore after page change in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I use jQuery Mobile 1.4.5. When I load a page and right away click the mobile menu toggle button, the mobile menu opens. When I change pages, the mobile menu does not open anymore when I click the toggle button.

My navigation looks like this:

```
<div data-role="header">
   <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="{{ url('_my_page_1') }}">Page 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="{{ url('_my_page_2') }}">Page 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="{{ url('_my_page_3') }}">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>

      <a id="toggle-mobile-menu" href="javascript:void(0)" data-role="none">
         Toggle mobile menu
      </a>

      <ul id="mobile-menu">
         // ...
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
<div data-role="content"></div>
```

```js
$(function () {
   $(document).on('click','#toggle-mobile-menu', function() {
            $('#mobile-menu').fadeToggle();
   });
});
```

How do I need to adapt my code?

Comment: Your code is looking good. Are you sure this code is visible to all the pages? Did you try putting break points on this code and check if it is being called when you click on the button?

Comment: @Medard Yes, I am sure. Even if I put the script code inside my header div, the mobile menu only opens after initial page load in my browser, but not after changing pages via the navigation (please note: content gets loaded via ajax, as it is jQuery Mobile).

Comment: `$(document).on("pagecreate", function () { $("menu").off("click").on("click", function() { do something } });`

Comment: @Omar Unfortunately, this code does not work. I inserted an 'alert('pagechange')' inside the inner function, and I noticed that on page change it gets fired twice...

Comment: So you have the same button in all pages with same id?

Answer (score 0):

Use just one external toolbar and place the markup outside the page within the body of your page. It's easy: the markup remains the same.
Don't forget to initialize the toolbar: because external toolbars are not within a page, you must call the toolbar plugin yourself.

In `$(document).ready` add this:

```
$(function(){
    $( "[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']" ).toolbar();
});
```

Here is the jQuery Mobile documentation about this topic:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/toolbar-external/

and here for fixed toolbars:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/toolbar-fixed-external/